# Grafana Dashboard Displays Different Values on Zoom In vs. Zoom Out

Tags: grafana

I'm experiencing an issue with my Grafana dashboard where I'm seeing different values for the same metric when I change the zoom level. When I'm zoomed in, I see the actual value at a particular timestamp, but when I zoom out, the value changes.

For instance, at the same timestamp, the zoomed-in view shows a temperature value of 18.5°C, but when zoomed out, it displays as 18°C as if it was truncated.

[image: zoomed out viz]
[image: zoomed in viz]

Details:

Grafana Version: 10.3.1
Data Source: SQLite db
Pluging used: frser-sqlite-datasource

Could anyone explain why this is happening and how to adjust the settings so that the zoomed-out view reflects the actual data points more accurately?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use Inspect query option of the Grafana's panels. Check what exact data is returned there, and if mismatch is present in numbers too - get queries for both cases, run them locally on your data source and investigate from that

Comment: thanks for your answer. The issue is coming from grafana query result. the results are different see imgur.com/a/5q5cMAk
Do you have an idea, why does it behave like this ?

Comment: If results are different for two ranges, than this in fact means that problem is not in the grafana. Investigate your queries and identify why it produces different results depending on the parameters.